# Do I need to watch Annabelle before Annabelle 2?

Tags: annabelle, annabelle-creation, the-conjuring-universe

Like the title says, must I watch the original film, or can [Annabelle 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5140878/?ref_=nv_sr_1) be watched as a stand-alone movie?

Comment: I haven't watched the second one, so I won't put this as an answer. But Annabelle (1), pretty much gives her origin, so I would say that it is at least interesting to watch it first.

Comment: @LeonX but  Annabelle was so so bad film

Comment: @TommyTommy I didn't even know this movie existed. But at the start of Annabelle, there's the scene where she gets possessed.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Well, I didn't hate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Annabelle 2" is a prequel, so it is an origin story, and you don't need any prior information.

If you have seen many of the other Blumhouse Productions films, you will notice lots of connections ("Easter Eggs"), including post-credit scenes.

A lot like "Ouijia: Origin of Evil", "Annabelle: Creation" takes a more successful horror-thriller director and does a substantially better prequel to an otherwise forgettable first film.

If you like obvious jump scares and creepy atmosphere and especially if you liked "Lights Out" or "Ouijia: Origin of Evil", go see "Annabelle: Creation" for sure.

The only reason you will "need" to see "Annabelle" first, is to fully understand the post-credits sequence -- but it's pretty obvious without seeing the original movie.